# Php throwing sqli count errors

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```js
<? php

include_once("connection.php");

// email and password sent from form 
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$email = stripslashes($email);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count = mysqli_num_rows($connection, $result);

// If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
if ($count == 1) {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
  $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
}

?>
```

```html
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>


    <form class="pop" method="post" action="login.php">

      <p class="login">LOGIN</p>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="left-inner-addon "><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i>
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="left-inner-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i>
          <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>Forgot Password?</p>

      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" role="button" name="login" id="login">LOGIN</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
<? php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$db = 'members';

$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db);

if ($connection) {
  echo "Connected Successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error connecting: . mysqli_connect_error()";
}

?>
```

I have index.php, connection.php and login.php files. I have already created register.php for sign up it's working fine. In login.php, it is connected successfully but throwing an error in Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given 
One more thing I want to figure out how do I know if the users is login in my website I means I want to find out if it is stored to the database or I don't know as I'm new to SQL and after login there should valid or invalid email and password but not showing. In my database, I have created table the list of id, username, email, password. Please help in proper way and simple, don't confuse me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mysqli_num_rows() function returns the number of rows in a result set.

It accepts only one parameter say $result which is Required. $result is a result set identifier returned by mysqli_query(), mysqli_store_result() or mysqli_use_result(). You are passing the $connection object along with the $result which causes the issue.

For saving sessions in Database, reffer these posts

[Storing Sessions in a Database](http://shiflett.org/articles/storing-sessions-in-a-database)

or

[Saving PHP's Session data to a database](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/session-handler.html)

Comment: Thanks guy. it is success fully connected. But how do I find out if the users is login.

Comment: Reffer http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp and also the other two posts for session handling related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

config.php

```
< ?php
$mysql_hostname = "hostname";
$mysql_user = "username";
$mysql_password = "password";
$mysql_database = "database";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password)
or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
?>
```

Login.php

```
include("config.php");
session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
// username and password sent from Form
$myemailid=addslashes($_POST['emailid']);
$mypassword=addslashes($_POST['password']);

$sql="SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$myemailid' and    passcode='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$active=$row['active'];
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
```

**Session** -> variables hold information about one single user, and are available to all pages in one application

```
if($count==1)
{
session_register("myusername");
$_SESSION['login_user']=$myusername;

header("location: welcome.php");
}
else
{
$error="Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
}
}
?>
```

Logout.php

```
< ?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy())
{
header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: I fill up as your method but still I don't understand how I check it if the user login? It showing it is connecting succesfully that doesn't redirect to another page with no username like Greeting (username)

Comment: after successfull database connection,write a query to check the email and password in database . for Eg:user table.using select query like "SELECT id FROM UserTable WHERE emailid='$myemailid' and    passcode='$mypassword'"; .then check the  result of this query ,if the data is empty or not,if it is empty,then  redirect to login page like header("Location: http://www.example.com/login.php");other wise create a session and redirect to welcome page.

Comment: where i should query from database or in php file?

Comment: you have to write in  a php file only , i mean  to write a select query in that php file itself

Comment: Ok now I got it you means when i type sql it will add to database. Once it is successful connected then I have to replace query in sql. Am I right?

Comment: I want to know your using WHERE username='$myemailid' and    passcode='$mypassword'";  username is input name and myemailid is database name. Is that right?

Comment: no no..  username and passcode is a column in a table(eg:USER TABLE). i think you have to refer some links for basic of writing a  query.check on to this how to write a query .like http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp  and refer this for user login this may help you more detail ,http://www.formget.com/login-form-in-php/. :)

Comment: ok got it i was confused at first. I think i should read basic query.. I understand a little but php code confused me where to put and what to put...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106320/discussion-between-nitheesh-k-p-and-alzira-barretto).